# How to load a file from a combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, io

I'm currently have the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dir = "Path\path\path"
    For Each file As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))
    Next

End Sub
```

This code finds a directory and populates a combobox with names of all the files in that directory. I would like to be able to select the file name from the combobox and the file be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-click on a combobox, when combobox item changes - launch the file listed in the combobox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = ComboBox1.Text
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "Path\path\path"
    proc.Start()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must replace GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) with GetFileName(file) because it could enter duplicates

Then just add this code:

```
Process.Start(dir & combobox1.selectedText)
```

Comment: Where would I add this code? I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Just double click on the combobox and the function handling combobox.selectedindexchanged event will be created. Add the code into it

Comment: Or add a button and add the code on button.click event

Comment: I have tried it on the combobox.selectedindexchanged event but, Im getting and error..... Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Open' accepts this number of arguments

Comment: Try    Process.Start(dir & combobox1.selectedText)

Comment: Same error with button as well... BTW thanks for your help so far. :)

Comment: Process is found in System.Diagnostics

Comment: almost... it loads but when i get to the point of loading the file i get the following message box:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.

Comment: Make sure that combobox.selectedText is returning value and try to replace it by combobox.Text

Comment: Make sure that the value passed to process.start() is a full file path. Ex : "C:\folder\abc.txt"

Comment: Thank You for all Your Help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
Private Sub LoadCombo(filesFromPath As String) Handles Button1.Click

    cbo.DisplayMemeber = "Name"
    cbo.ValueMemeber = "Value"
    cbo.DataSource = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir).
        Select(Function(f) New With { .Name = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), .Value = f})


End Sub

Private Sub cbo_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbo.SelectedIndexChanged

    If cbo.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return
    If Not File.Exist(cbo.SelectedItem.Value) Then Return '<-- this is late 
    ' binding that comes with anonymous type.) 

    Dim p As New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = cbo.SelectedItem.Value '<-- this is late binding that comes with anonymous type. 
    ' you can also declare your type and use :
    ' p.StartInfo.FileName = DirectCastcbo(cbo.SelectedItem, yourType).Value
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    p.Start();
End Sub
```